# Having an issue to react-native init an application

Tags: react-native

Trying to follow the React-Native Getting Started docs, and came across the init application problem after I typed "`react-native init rnApp`" in the terminal.

**Here is the snippet of the error**:
[image]

By the way, the node and npm version on my machine are:

```
node --version: v8.11.2
npm --version: 6.4.1
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

react-native init currently isn't really that stable with newer versions of node. There is a whole collection of different stack overflow questions and github questions regarding this. Downgrade your node version and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which specific version should I downgrade to? Btw, I fixed the issue by deleting the node_modules directory and npm install again. =)

Comment: It seems that people have success when downgrading to around version 8.6.0 or a little higher! Glad the node_modules fix worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Update the fix: just install `yarn` and then use it to add/install react-native-cli. This will run the ios simulator smoothly (able to code and update it correspondingly).

Comment: Forgot to add: may need to add `react-native start --reset-cache` if facing the bundle failed error. Check here for more info: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21530